# Share config file with multiple project in same solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-config

My project use `Entity Framework 6 Database First` for the DAL, and it need to have a `connectionString` in every project's config file.

As I have multi project in solution, I found that it can be a problem if I need to modify connection string, which I need to check every config file.

So I come up an idea, create a *Share* config file under the solution directory.
The structure:

```
+ Solution
  - CommonConfig
    - Share.Debug.config
    - Share.Release.config
  - Project1
    - web.config
      - web.Debug.config
      - web.Release.config
    - Share.Debug.config (Add with Link)
    - Share.Release.config (Add with Link)
  - Project2
    ...
```

And I have move the `connectionString` section to `Share.xxx.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="db" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

First test with `configSource`, it work without problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
      <connectionStrings configSource="bin\Share.Debug.config"/>
...
</configuration>
```

Then I have remove whole section for `connectionString`
And modify the `web.Debug.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings configSource="bin\Share.Debug.config" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But it doesn't work, the EF cannot find the `connectionString` with this setting.

Will it a problem if I want to add a whole section instead of a node?

**EDIT**
After read several post, some said the transform only work when I publish the website, so I try to publish it to my local IIS.

When I create and preview the publish profile, it return error

> A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.

Comment: If you have multiple project then the connection string will be used from the project that is accessing your layer. For example, if you have entity framework in DAL class library then the connection string should be placed in presentation layer. No need to add it to DAL layer. The only problem arise if you use Database first approach in which edmx will be updated using your DAL connection string. Can you tell me which approach you are using with Entity Framework?

Comment: Sadly... I'm using EF DB First.  And I have 3 websites, 1 Web API project, 1 class project in same solution, and access the same EF...

Comment: Which projects are accessing your DAL layer having edmx?

Comment: Actually all projects